# Bootstrap Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine, bootstrap-table

I am trying to test the bootstrap table where the bootstrap table is loaded from cdn. This is my fixture file for Jasmine test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
<script src="<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
"  type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="Table" class ="hidden">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="foo">foo</th>
            <th data-field="foo1">foo1</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = [ 
                                       {"foo" : "foo",
                                                "foo1 : 3   } ];
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/main/webapp/javascript/foodata.js"></script>
```

I am trying to Jasmine test this table.Here is my js file:

/**
 * Calls the BootStrap table with the foo data along with the pagination
 */

```
    $(function(){
    var table= $('#Table').bootstrapTable({
    data : foo,
    pagination: true,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100]
    });
    table.removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

When I try to run the spec it shows XMLHTTP error. If I use the bootstrap tale js file it loads perfectly. But when I use CDN for bootstrap table it doesn't. Is there any way I can use CDN in fixture?

Comment: What's the deal with that `<script src="<script src="` thing?

Comment: Could you add to your question an example of the expected behavior of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors on the code, in the script tag including the bootstrap-table, also you should include jquery to make it work. Also you had some errors in the variable named foo.

```js
$(function(){
    var table= $('#Table').bootstrapTable({
    data : foo,
    pagination: true,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100]
    });
    table.removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="Table" class ="hidden">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="foo">foo</th>
            <th data-field="foo1">foo1</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = [ {"foo" : "foo","foo1" : 3   } ];
</script>
```